# Proving that $ \operatorname{Re} \bigg( \int_\gamma f(z) \,dz \bigg) \neq \int_\gamma {Re}\big(f(z) \big)\,dz $

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Im trying to show that in general

$$ \operatorname{Re} \bigg( \int_\gamma f(z) \,dz \bigg) \neq  \int_\gamma  {Re}\big(f(z) \big)\,dz  $$

I have found plenty of examples that show that the above relation is generally true. However is it possible to prove it without finding specific examples where

$$ \operatorname{Re} \bigg( \int_\gamma f(z) \,dz \bigg) =  \int_\gamma  {Re}\big(f(z) \big)\,dz  $$

is not true?

Comment: No. You need a counterexample.

Comment: I mean, you could probably prove it in some funny indirect way, like, if the equation is true for a given $f$, then it's not true for $\exp(f)$, or something like that (this example just off the top of my head, no idea if it's actually true). But counterexamples are definitely easier.